# Trying to compare html datetime with current time for conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, jquery-selectors

I have a sharepoint discussion list. There's a field called "Last Updated". I'm trying to highlight rows where last updated is greater than 1 hour.

[image]

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.6.0/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var now = moment().format('l h:mm:ss a');
                console.log(now);

                //$row = $("td .ms-vb2:contains('6/13/2014 9:46 AM')");
                $rows = $("td[id$='WPQ3'] .ms-vb2:contains('AM'), td[id$='WPQ3'] .ms-vb2:contains('PM')");
                console.log($rows);
                $times = $rows.children
                $rows.parent().css("background-color", "rgba(203, 231, 57, 0.37)");

            });         
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Right now, every cell is highlighted based on my selector.

$rows contains 2 objects and the innerText for both objects contains the time, so something like "6/13/2014 9:46 AM".

I'm not sure how to look at the time for each row, compare it with the `now` variable and then highlight if my condition is met, which is "Highlight if less than 1 hour difference"

Comment: I think you can customize that view and do conditional formatting, if you don't mind going outside the jquery selector stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Get minutes between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709803/javascript-get-minutes-between-two-dates)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama I don't mind going outside of Javascript to accomplish this but SharePoint is pretty limited when it comes to conditional formatting based on time.

Comment: Fair enough. I would work on converting the `innerText` into a date object and then walk through some of the comparisons tutorials to get minutes/hour differences between dates w/ jquery/javascript

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using moment.js and a bit more research into jQuery.

Here's my solution:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //STORE CURRENT TIME 
            var now = moment() 
            //GET ALL ROWS I'M TRYING TO HIGHLIGHT
            $rows = $("td[id$='WPQ3'] .ms-vb2:contains('AM'), td[id$='WPQ3'] .ms-vb2:contains('PM')");

            //GO THROUGH EACH ROW FOUND
            $.each($rows, function (index, row){

                //FOR EACH ROW CONVERT TIME INTO MOMEMTJS OBJECT
                var lastUpdateTime = moment(row.innerText)

                //USING MOMENT JS, FIND THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN LAST UPDATE AND NOW
                var difference = now.diff(lastUpdateTime, 'hours');

                //IF THE DIFFERENCE IS LESS THAN AN HOUR HIGHLIGHT THE CURRENT ROWA
                if(difference <= 1){
                    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgba(203, 231, 57, 0.37)");
                }
            })
        });
```