# Get the Difference Between Two Dates in Minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have two dates `startdate` and `currentdate`.

How can I get the difference between the two dates **in minutes**

```
console.log("startdate: " + startdate + " currentdate: " + currentdate);
>> startdate: Tue Nov 10 2015 13:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) 
>> currentdate: Tue Nov 10 2015 11:55:53 GMT-0800 (PST)

console.log(startdate.getTime() - currentdate.getTime());
>> 3846736
```

I'm able to subtract the two dates, but I'm unsure of how to convert that output (`output: 3846736`) into minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Get minutes between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709803/javascript-get-minutes-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the units:

```
var milliseconds = (startdate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime());
var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
```

Or, all in one:

```
var minutes = (startdate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
```

This will give you a big decimal most likely.  For rounding, use `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`, or `Math.round`.