# Difference between two dates in hrs and mins

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two dates in millis **1513885098821** & **1513885078742**.
How to display the difference between above two dates in hrs and mins like `2 hrs 31 mins`. 
If moment have any option then its good, solution using plain javascript is also ok for me.
I tried below

```
moment(new Date(txn.toDate - txn.fromDate)).format('HH mm')
```

But it gives **05 30** result. 
Output of below line is

```
new Date(1513885098821 - 1513885078742);
```

result: **Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709819/1715121

Comment: Try `moment.diff()`: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: @csp713 It will give diff either in hours or secs not both. Is there any way I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably countless answers already to help you find the difference between two dates, either using `moment js` or simply the native javascript Date object. Since you are having difficulty though, here is an example using `moment js` and its `diff` function:

```
// use timestamps to create moment objects
const startDate = moment.utc(1513885098821);
const endDate = moment.utc(1513885078742);

const hourDiff = startDate.diff(endDate, 'hours');
console.log(hourDiff); // 0
const minuteDiff = startDate.diff(endDate, 'minutes');
console.log(minuteDiff); // 0
const secondDiff = startDate.diff(endDate, 'seconds');
console.log(secondDiff); // 20

console.log(`${hourDiff}hrs ${minuteDiff}mins ${secondDiff}sec`); // 0hrs 0mins 20sec
```

Or try it online [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k0w4fjks/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Date`, just do this:

```
prettyMillisDiff(millis1, millis2) {
    let minDiff = (millis1 - millis2)/60000;
    if (minDiff < 0) {
        minDiff *= -1;
    }
    const hours = Math.floor(minDiff/60);
    const mins =  Math.floor(minDiff%60);
    console.log(`${hours} hours ${mins} mins`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try splitting string  from the first method.

```
var k=moment(new Date(txn.toDate - txn.fromDate)).format('HH mm');
var frmt=k.split(' ');
var min=frmt+'mm';
var hr=frmt+'fr';
```