# If not evaluating the negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following code  to check if the time difference is greater than 60 minutes.
If the difference is less than 60 then false should return to console else true.
Here when I use two time format (as mentioned in below code), the output is -1310 which is greater than -1380 but still it is returning the false . I am expecting true.

below is the code:

```
var currDay = new Date("2018-02-21T23:40:00+05:30");
console.log(currDay);
var nextDay = new Date("2018-02-22T01:50:00+05:30");
console .log(nextDay);

var currTime = (currDay.getHours() + ':' + currDay.getMinutes()).split(':');
console.log(currTime);
var currTimeHourToMinutes = parseInt(currTime[0]*60);
var currTimeMinutespart = parseInt(currTime[1]);
var TotalCurrTimeInMinutes = parseInt(currTimeHourToMinutes + currTimeMinutespart) ;
console.log(TotalCurrTimeInMinutes);

var deptTime = (nextDay.getHours() + ':' + nextDay.getMinutes()).split(':');
console.log(deptTime);
var depTimeHourToMinutes = parseInt(deptTime[0]*60);
var deptTimeMinutespart = parseInt(deptTime[1]);
var TotalDeptTimeInMinutes = parseInt(depTimeHourToMinutes+ deptTimeMinutespart);
console.log(TotalDeptTimeInMinutes);

var diffInArrivalAndDeptTime = TotalDeptTimeInMinutes-TotalCurrTimeInMinutes;
console.log(diffInArrivalAndDeptTime);
if((diffInArrivalAndDeptTime >= "60") &&  (diffInArrivalAndDeptTime > "-1380") ) 
{
   console.log("true1");
}

else
{
    console.log("false");
}
```

P.S. I am using Chrome Developer Snippets to run above code.

Comment: Firstly your logic to calculate the difference in minutes is massively over-complicated. It's a one-liner. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709803/javascript-get-minutes-between-two-dates). With regard to why you always get a `false` outut, it's because you're comparing strings, not ints.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan, Thank you for this , the simple script also worked the same for me but again how would I compare an output with the negative number ? using "" is treating the -1380 as string.

Comment: you must convert the strings to numbers... parseInt() or parseFloat()

Comment: Or just remove the quotes: eg. `diffInArrivalAndDeptTime >= 60`

Comment: @AmbikaTewari Look at the answer with 90 upvotes (bottom one). That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two dates gives the difference in milliseconds. Divide by 60000 to get minutes.

```
date1 = new Date(*/some date*/);
date2 = new Date(*/some date*/);
diffInMinutes = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 60000;
```

Comment: Thank you all... It s working now, I compared the result with parsInt(-1380) and that helped.