# Calculate amount of minutes between 2 dates which took to make a track

Tags: javascript, time

I have an array of tracks.

```
const history = [
  {
    entryDate: "2022-05-03T09:32:07.137+02:00",
    type: "statusChange",
    message: "",

  },
  {
    entryDate: "2022-05-02T19:32:07.137+02:00",
    type: "statusChange",
    message: "",
  },

  {
    entryDate: "2022-05-02T09:32:07.137+02:00",
    type: "statusChange",
    message: "",
  },
  {
    entryDate: "2022-05-02T07:30:01.672+02:00",
    type: "statusChange",
    message: "",
  }
];
```

How to get the number of minutes that was tracked only during given times, for example:
How many minutes was the user tracked from 09:30 - 18:00 from the given array of tracks?

Hard to figure it out myself.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709803/javascript-get-minutes-between-two-dates

Comment: Hey James, thank you for your reply. But it's not about the difference between two dates (which is pretty simple), Im talking about calculating minutes between 2 dates and the time of a given time. 


For Example:
I have track started at 07:30 and it ends at 10:00 
and I know that working hours are from 09:00 to 18:00
I need to calculate the minutes between them. (which will be 60 minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you know which elements in the array are “workstart” vs “workend” events.  Assuming you have that part figured out, and that you have four date variables workStart, workEnd, trackStart, trackEnd, which are numeric:

```
let start = Math.max(workstart, trackstart);
let end = Math.min(workend, trackend);
let result = end > start ? end - start : 0;
```

Comment: the last element in the array it's a start track. First, it's the end track. 

but it's a date, does Math.max can compare a date?

Comment: it works partially; for example, it calculates everything if the track happens during one exact date. 

It would be interesting if it's possible to split it for multiple days. Or better to iterate between pairs of dates and found amount of minutes? What do you think will be a better approach?

Comment: It they are JavaScript Date objects then yes.  result will be in milliseconds.

Comment: I createad samll sandbox to show result:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dan-9530mn?file=/src/index.js -
Looks like a value not correct :( 

total minutes in this example must be 602 minutes, but I got 1472

Comment: Start and End dates should all be on the same day.