# Can someone help me calculate time (hours) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta235.png)

I have a web application that has two calendars (Date Pickers). The first calendar called startDate has two timepickers, startTime1 and endTime1, and a checkbox called allDayCheckbox1 that disables or enables these timepickers. The second calendar called endDate has two timepickers, startTime2 and endTime2, and a checkbox called allDayCheckbox2 that disables or enables these timepickers. I have a textbox called hoursRequested that should display the calculated time. I need time calculated with the following parameters in JavaScript.

1. Each full day counts as 7.5 hours
2. Weekends and all federal holidays do not count as hours and should be skipped
3. If the checkboxes are checked, the time in the timepickers are not counted
4. If the checkboxes are not checked, the time in the timepickers is counted towards the total number of hours.
5. Here are some examples of how the hours should be counted.

- Example 1, if StartDate is October 23, 2013 and the EndDate is October 27, 2023, and both of the allDayCheckbox checkboxes are checked, the total hours should be 37.50
- Example 2, if the StartDate is October 23, 2013, and the EndDate is October 27, 2023, and the allDayCheckbox1 is unchecked, and startTime1 is set to 12:00 p.m. and endTime1 is set to 4:30 p.m., and allDayCheckbox2 is checked, the total hours should be 34.50 hours.

Here is my HTML code,

```
 <label for="startDate" class="ml-4" style="margin-top: 20px;">When does it begin?</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="date" id="startDate" class="form-control" value="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="container">
</div>


                        <label for="startTime1" class="mt-2">From:</label>
                        <input type="time" id="startTime1" class="form-control" value="07:00" disabled>

                        <label for="startTime2" class="mt-2">To:</label>
                        <input type="time" id="startTime2" class="form-control" value="07:00" disabled>
                        <label class="CheckBoxContainer" style="font-size:20px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="allDayCheckbox1" checked="checked" onchange="toggleTimePickers('startTime1', 'startTime2', this)">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>All Day
                        </label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="endDate" class="ml-4" style="margin-top: 20px;">When does it end?</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control ml-4" value="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>">
                        </div>
                        <label for="endTime1" class="mt-2 ml-4">From:</label>
                        <input type="time" id="endTime1" class="form-control ml-4" value="07:00" disabled>

                        <label for="endTime2" class="mt-2 ml-4">To:</label>
                        <input type="time" id="endTime2" class="form-control ml-4" value="07:00" disabled>
                         <label class="CheckBoxContainer" style="font-size:20px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="allDayCheckbox2" checked="checked" onchange="toggleTimePickers('endTime1', 'endTime2', this)" >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>All Day
                      </label>


<input type="text" id="hoursRequested" class="form-control" readonly="">
```

Here is my JavaScript code that disables my timepickers,

```
 function toggleTimePickers(startTimeId, endTimeId, checkbox) {
     const startTimeInput = document.getElementById(startTimeId);
     const endTimeInput = document.getElementById(endTimeId);

     startTimeInput.disabled = checkbox.checked;
     endTimeInput.disabled = checkbox.checked;
     


 }
```

Before I get, "Share the code that you've tried", I've tried probably 20 different ways to calculate the time the way I want. None of them worked correctly. Here is my current code to calculate the hours between two dates. It mostly works but isn't consistent for some reason when I change the dates and I was unable to exclude weekends and holidays in this code.

```
 function calculateHours() {

     const startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
     const endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);
     const dateOneObj = new Date(startDate);
     const dateTwoObj = new Date(endDate);
     const milliseconds = Math.abs(dateTwoObj - dateOneObj);
     const Hours = milliseconds / 36e5;
     const totalHours = Hours / 3.2 + 7.5;
     const hoursRequestedInput = document.getElementById("hoursRequested");

     hoursRequestedInput.value = totalHours.toFixed(2); 
 }
```

I am now just learning JavaScript, so please understand that I'm asking as a newborn in this language. I'll be happy to hear suggestions on websites, courses, and books to learn. Thanks to anyone who is able to help.

I've tried many combinations of code, none have worked. Here is but one of the many combinations that didn't work.

```
function calculateTotalHours() {
    const startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value);
    const endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value);
    const allDayCheckbox1 = document.getElementById('allDayCheckbox1').checked;
    const allDayCheckbox2 = document.getElementById('allDayCheckbox2').checked;
    const startTime1 = document.getElementById('startTime1').value;
    const startTime2 = document.getElementById('startTime2').value;
    const endTime1 = document.getElementById('endTime1').value;
    const endTime2 = document.getElementById('endTime2').value;

    const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // One day in milliseconds
    const totalHours = 0;

    const daysDifference = Math.round((endDate - startDate) / oneDay) + 1;

    
    for (const i = 0; i < daysDifference; i++) {
        const currentDate = new Date(startDate);
        currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);

    
        const isWeekend = currentDate.getDay() === 0 || currentDate.getDay() === 6;
        const isHoliday = false; 

        if (!isWeekend && !isHoliday) {
            if (allDayCheckbox1) {
                totalHours += 7.5;
            } else {
                // Calculate hours based on start and end times
                const startParts = startTime1.split(':').map(Number);
                const endParts = startTime2.split(':').map(Number);

                const startMinutes = startParts[0] * 60 + startParts[1];
                const endMinutes = endParts[0] * 60 + endParts[1];

                totalHours += (endMinutes - startMinutes) / 60;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!allDayCheckbox2) {
        const startParts = endTime1.split(':').map(Number);
        const endParts = endTime2.split(':').map(Number);

        const startMinutes = startParts[0] * 60 + startParts[1];
        const endMinutes = endParts[0] * 60 + endParts[1];

        totalHours += (endMinutes - startMinutes) / 60;
    }

    document.getElementById('hoursRequested').value = totalHours.toFixed(2);
}

// Initial calculation
calculateTotalHours();
```

Here is another attempt,

```
function calculateHours() {
  const startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
  const endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);
  const startTime = document.getElementById("startTime1").value;
  const endTime = document.getElementById("endTime1").value;
  const allDayCheckbox = document.getElementById("allDayCheckbox1");
  const hoursRequestedInput = document.getElementById("hoursRequested");

  let totalHours = 0;
  
  for (let currentDate = startDate; currentDate <= endDate; currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1)) {
    const dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay(); // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ..., 6 = Saturday
    const isWeekend = dayOfWeek === 0 || dayOfWeek === 6; // Saturday or Sunday

    if (isWeekend || federalHolidays.some(holiday => holiday.toDateString() === currentDate.toDateString())) {
      continue; // Skip weekends and holidays
    }

    if (allDayCheckbox.checked || currentDate.toDateString() === startDate.toDateString()) {
      if (currentDate.toDateString() === startDate.toDateString()) {
        // Calculate hours for the first day
        const startDateTime = new Date(`${currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]}T${startTime}`);
        const endDateTime = new Date(`${currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]}T${endTime}`);
        const timeDifference = endDateTime - startDateTime;
        const hours = timeDifference / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        totalHours += hours;
      } else {
        // Add 7.5 hours for each working day
        totalHours += 7.5;
      }
    }
  }

  hoursRequestedInput.value = totalHours.toFixed(2); // Display with two decimal places
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - Get minutes between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709803/javascript-get-minutes-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kept your HTML pretty much intact, but added onchange eventlisteners to each of the input fields so that your function runs whenever someone adjusts their answer so that the total is calculated live. (feel free to remove this if undesired).

The holidays will have to be added to the list (New years is currently added as an example).

```js
// You'll need to complete this list or grab a list of holidays to pull from
const federalHolidays = [
  new Date("2023-01-01"),

];

function convertTimeToNumber(timeString) {
    const [hours, minutes] = timeString.split(':');
    const hoursAsNumber = parseInt(hours, 10);
    const minutesAsNumber = parseInt(minutes, 10);
    return hoursAsNumber + minutesAsNumber / 60;
}

function isWeekendOrHoliday(date) {
  const dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
  return dayOfWeek === 0 || dayOfWeek === 6 || federalHolidays.some(holiday => holiday.toDateString() === date.toDateString());
}

function calculateTotalHours() {
  const start = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value);
  const end = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value);
  const allDayCheckbox1 = document.getElementById('allDayCheckbox1').checked;
  const allDayCheckbox2 = document.getElementById('allDayCheckbox2').checked;

  let totalHours = 0;

  for (let currentDate = new Date(start); currentDate <= end; currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1)) {
    //toggle time input fields
    if (allDayCheckbox1) {
      startTime1.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      startTime2.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    } else {
      startTime1.removeAttribute('disabled');
      startTime2.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    if (allDayCheckbox2) {
      endTime1.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      endTime2.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    }
    else {
      endTime1.removeAttribute('disabled');
      endTime2.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

    //calculate total hours
    if (isWeekendOrHoliday(currentDate)) {
      continue;
    }
    else if ( currentDate.toISOString() == start.toISOString() && !allDayCheckbox1) {
      var startDateOpen = convertTimeToNumber(startTime1.value);
      var startDateClose = convertTimeToNumber(startTime2.value);
      totalHours += startDateClose - startDateOpen;
    }
    else if (currentDate.toISOString() == end.toISOString() && !allDayCheckbox2) {
      var endDateOpen = convertTimeToNumber(endTime1.value);
      var endDateClose = convertTimeToNumber(endTime2.value);
      totalHours += endDateClose - endDateOpen;
    }
    else {
    totalHours += 7.5;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('hoursRequested').value = totalHours.toFixed(2);
}

calculateTotalHours();
```

```html
<label for="startDate" class="ml-4" style="margin-top: 20px;">When does it begin?</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="date" id="startDate" class="form-control" value="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString(" yyyy-MM-dd ") %>">
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>


<label for="startTime1" class="mt-2">From:</label>
<input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="time" id="startTime1" class="form-control" value="07:00" disabled>

<label for="startTime2" class="mt-2">To:</label>
<input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="time" id="startTime2" class="form-control" value="07:00" disabled>
<label class="CheckBoxContainer" style="font-size:20px">
                    <input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="checkbox" id="allDayCheckbox1" checked="checked">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>All Day
                        </label>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="endDate" class="ml-4" style="margin-top: 20px;">When does it end?</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control ml-4" value="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString(" yyyy-MM-dd ") %>">
  </div>
  <label for="endTime1" class="mt-2 ml-4">From:</label>
  <input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="time" id="endTime1" class="form-control ml-4" value="07:00" disabled>

  <label for="endTime2" class="mt-2 ml-4">To:</label>
  <input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="time" id="endTime2" class="form-control ml-4" value="07:00" disabled>
  <label class="CheckBoxContainer" style="font-size:20px">
                    <input onchange="calculateTotalHours()" type="checkbox" id="allDayCheckbox2" checked="checked" >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>All Day
                      </label>

  <br>
  <input type="text" id="hoursRequested" class="form-control" readonly="">
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! This worked perfectly! I tried so hard to get it and I'll be studying your answer to understand where I went wrong. If there are any websites, books, or courses that you'd recommend for me to learn, I'd appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: This also took me a bit of time too! The one suggestion I'd make is to consider whether the time fields are best utilized for the start date and the end date or if they are better utilized on a daily basis. If this is for users to enter in time the one issue I can see is if a user needs to adjust the time worked on a specific day between the start and end dates.

Comment: This will be used for leave requests so it won't be used for daily entries. You have any suggestions that helped you learn JavaScript? Again, I can't thank you enough! This is really helpful in my JS learning journey :)

Comment: These are wicked help - https://javascript30.com/

Comment: Also projects like this time tracker are a great way to learn. One thing I also did was read through the entire JavaScript documentation and take notes on every section (boring) - https://devdocs.io/javascript/

Comment: ALSO, getting a firm grasp of HTML and CSS really helps. This book is one I tend to recommend - HTML and CSS: Design and Build Websites Paperback (by Jon Duckett)

Comment: Man, this is great stuff.  I'll be going through all this and just continue to get better. You've been super helpful! Thanks a million!