# JavaScript calculate time difference always returns 59 minutes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the time difference between now and a future time that is about 24 hours from now. However, the minutes parameter always returns 59. Here is my code:

```js
function formatTimeDifference(startTimestamp) {
  //add 24 hours to time they signed up to get expiry
  const endTimestamp = startTimestamp + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  
  const timeDifference = endTimestamp - now;

  const hours = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));

  //format the result
  return `${hours} hours ${minutes} mins.`;
}

console.log(formatTimeDifference(1710860076));
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scooke/wyempohn/

Comment: You're adding a number representing seconds to a number representing milliseconds.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript?rq=2 and [JavaScript - Get minutes between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7709803/215552) for how it should be done.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? You're adding something that resembles 24 hours to a random `startTimestamp` - what makes you think that the difference between the **current** date and that calculated date should be different?

Comment: Your `startTimestamp` value is wrong because you forgot to multiply by 1000. JavaScript timestamps are milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Try printing `new Date(startTimestamp)` and you'll see how wrong it is.

Comment: @Barmar but then `now` compensates by being converted to seconds. The problem is adding milliseconds instead of seconds to `startTimestamp`. Then there is other mixing of milliseconds and seconds in the conversion. If sticking to one of the two time units it works.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you are correct. I was working with seconds. All fixed, thank you.

Comment: why do you divide `Date.now()` by `1e3`? Your `endTimestamp` is `miniseconds` but you calculate `timeDiff` by taking `miniseconds - seconds` which is a logic error